# Update Global var with setInterval Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phaser-framework

I am building a game with Phaser 3. I have an ajax call I want to make every second to get player data like so:

```
//Var is globally declared
var player1type;

create() {


 setInterval(function() {   

        function gameWaitingroom(getWaitingroom) {      

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '../includes/waitingroomcheck.php',
                cache: false,
                success: getWaitingroom


            });

        }
                // resolve/success callback

                gameWaitingroom(result => { 
                    try {
                        var waitingRoomData = JSON.parse(result);
                    }
                    catch (error) {
                        console.log('Error parsing JSON:', error, result);
                    }

                    //status = waitingRoomData.statusCode;
                    player1type = waitingRoomData.player1type;
                    console.log("INSIDE INTERVAL: "+player1type);

                }); 

    },1000);

console.log("OUTSIDE INTERVAL: "+player1type);

}
```

My console reads like so:

```
INSIDE INTERVAL: user
OUTSIDE INTERVAL: undefined
```

Why is var player1type undefined outside of the setInterval, but it works inside just fine, even though I’ve globally declared it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when the script first run the code in `setInterval()` will take 1s to be executed whiles the one outside it will be executed instantly. So by the time `console.log("OUTSIDE INTERVAL: "+player1type);` get executed, its value will be `undefined` that's because `player1type = waitingRoomData.player1type;` will still be waiting for 1s to be executed.

Comment: i believe you're correct, @ruleboy21, but can you recommend a way to amend this code so that I can get player1type outside of the setinterval?

Comment: found a solution that involved calling a function inside the set interval

Comment: @Dustin, as **ruleboy1** said it works already, as is. you only need to wait 1 Second _(plus the time it takes the server to respond)_ for the value to by filled by the callback of the ajax function.